# How to get an escaped space inside href of anchor tag

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In Asp.Net core (2.2) I need to escape a space inside a href of an anchor tag

```
@{
  var url = $"https://{Context.Request.Host}{Url.Action("SomeAction", "Projects")}/{Uri.EscapeUriString(Model.Name)}";
}
```

The url contains escaped spaces (%20), but using the url in a href of an anchor tag the %20 becomes a space again.

```
<a href="mailto:type@address.com?subject=Action:@(url)"
```

How to solve this?

Comment: You might have to escape it twice. Since it seems like you have two process that unescape the url

Comment: I tried "%2520", but then nothing will be unescaped, the "%2520" stays as part of the url.

Comment: Have you tried using + instead?

Comment: Yep, the plus remains a plus, but that's not valid for an url.

Comment: If it's in the query string part, [it is valid html](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application/x-www-form-urlencoded_type)

Comment: Guess I have to post process it in javascript